# Float bootstrap modal to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I'm using React bootstrap's `Modal` component.
It appears in the center of the screen by default.

How do i make it align to right instead? I have tried the following without any effect:

```
float: right;
margin-left: auto;
marigin-right: 0;
```

`margin-left: 65%;` works but not suitable for dynamic window size as modal content will be cut off.

Answer (score 4):

```css
/*******************************
* MODAL AS LEFT/RIGHT SIDEBAR
* Add "left" or "right" in modal parent div, after class="modal".
* Get free snippets on bootpen.com
*******************************/
 .modal.left .modal-dialog,
 .modal.right .modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
 }

 .modal.left .modal-content,
 .modal.right .modal-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
 }
 
 .modal.left .modal-body,
 .modal.right .modal-body {
  padding: 15px 15px 80px;
 }

/*Left*/
 .modal.left.fade .modal-dialog{
  left: -320px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
 }
 
 .modal.left.fade.in .modal-dialog{
  left: 0;
 }
        
/*Right*/
 .modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
  right: -320px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
 }
 
 .modal.right.fade.in .modal-dialog {
  right: 0;
 }

/* ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */
 .modal-content {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
 }

 .modal-header {
  border-bottom-color: #EEEEEE;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
 }

/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */
body {
 background-color: #78909C;
}

.demo {
 padding-top: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 110px;
}

.btn-demo {
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-radius: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-demo:focus {
 outline: 0;
}

.demo-footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: #212121;
 text-align: center;
}

.demo-footer > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container demo">

 <div class="text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   Left Sidebar Modal
  </button>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
   Right Sidebar Modal
  </button>
 </div>

 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal left fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Left Sidebar</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
     <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
     </p>
    </div>

   </div><!-- modal-content -->
  </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
 </div><!-- modal -->
 
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal right fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Right Sidebar</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
     <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
     </p>
    </div>

   </div><!-- modal-content -->
  </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
 </div><!-- modal -->
 
</div><!-- container -->
```

Comment: There is a minor change for recent version of react-bootstrap modal. Instead of '.in' in the style sheet use '.show' .

Answer (score 2):

For the Latest version instead of '.in' use '.show' as given below:

```css
/*******************************
* MODAL AS LEFT/RIGHT SIDEBAR
* Add "left" or "right" in modal parent div, after class="modal".
* Get free snippets on bootpen.com
*******************************/

.modal.right .modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
}

.modal.right .modal-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal.right .modal-body {
  padding: 15px 15px 80px;
}
      
/*Right*/
.modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
  right: -320px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal.right.fade.show .modal-dialog {
  right: 0;
}


/** ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */
 .modal-content {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
 }

 .modal-header {
  border-bottom-color: #EEEEEE;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*******************************
* MODAL AS LEFT/RIGHT SIDEBAR
* Add "left" or "right" in modal parent div, after class="modal".
* Get free snippets on bootpen.com
*******************************/
 .modal.left .modal-dialog,
 .modal.right .modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
 }

 .modal.left .modal-content,
 .modal.right .modal-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
 }
 
 .modal.left .modal-body,
 .modal.right .modal-body {
  padding: 15px 15px 80px;
 }

/*Left*/
 .modal.left.fade .modal-dialog{
  left: -320px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, left 0.3s ease-out;
 }
 
 .modal.left.fade.in .modal-dialog{
  left: 0;
 }
        
/*Right*/
 .modal.right.fade .modal-dialog {
  right: -320px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, right 0.3s ease-out;
 }
 
 .modal.right.fade.in .modal-dialog {
  right: 0;
 }

/* ----- MODAL STYLE ----- */
 .modal-content {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
 }

 .modal-header {
  border-bottom-color: #EEEEEE;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
 }

/* ----- v CAN BE DELETED v ----- */
body {
 background-color: #78909C;
}

.demo {
 padding-top: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 110px;
}

.btn-demo {
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border-radius: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-demo:focus {
 outline: 0;
}

.demo-footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: #212121;
 text-align: center;
}

.demo-footer > a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container demo">
 
 
 <div class="text-center">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   Left Sidebar Modal
  </button>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
   Right Sidebar Modal
  </button>
 </div>

 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal left fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Left Sidebar</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
     <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
     </p>
    </div>

   </div><!-- modal-content -->
  </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
 </div><!-- modal -->
 
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal right fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Right Sidebar</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
     <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
     </p>
    </div>

   </div><!-- modal-content -->
  </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
 </div><!-- modal -->
 
 
</div><!-- container -->

<footer class="demo-footer">
 <a href="http://www.bootpen.com" target="_blank">Get more code snippets</a>
</footer>
```